# How can I use MySQL NOT NULL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, notnull

I've form to insert values in MySQL database with PHP (Example code is below):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<style>
label{text-align:left;
       width:150px;
       display:block;
           float:left;
           clear:right;
       font-size:18;}

form {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<label>Name:</label><input name=name autocomplete=off><br>
<label>Date of Birth:</label><input size=2 name=dd placeholder=dd> / <input size=2 name=mm placeholder=mm> / <input size=6 name=yyyy placeholder=yyyy><br>
<label>Time of Birth:</label><input name=tob placeholder="hh : mm : ss"><br>
<label>City:</label><input name=city><br><br>
<center><input type=submit value=Save></center>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "userame";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB2";
if(empty($_POST["name"])){ echo "Name is Required<br>";}
else {
$name = $_POST["name"];
}
var_dump($name);
$tob = $_POST["tob"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$dd = $_POST["dd"];
$mm = $_POST["mm"];
$yyyy = $_POST["yyyy"];

$dob = "$yyyy-$mm-$dd";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Inserting Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO Person
VALUES('$name','$dob','$tob','$city')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

AND The COLUMN `Name` is set to **`varchar(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE`** data-type & constraint.

---

In-spite of

- `NOT NULL` constraint for `Name` Column, and
- `if(empty($_POST["name"])){ echo "Name is Required";}
  else {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  }`

When I inserts submit form without entering any value in Name Input in the form, I get following message (according to code)

```
Name is Required
NULL
New record created successfully
```

And My Database output like:

[image: screen0]

Here you can see that `var_dump($name)` says `$name` is **`NULL`** BUT Still MySQL Database accepting this value for `Name` Column!

---

So, My question is What is the use of `NOT NULL` or **How can I use MysQL `NOT NULL` with PHP?** for inserting data with the help for form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to translate PHP's `null` into SQL's `NULL` type appropriately. When you do simple string interpolation in PHP:

```
"INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('$bar')"
```

where `$bar` is `null`, the result ends up as:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('')
```

MySQL sees that as an empty string, which is not `NULL`, so it's fine.

You have to do something like this:

```
$value = null;
if ($value === null) {
    $bar = 'NULL';
} else {
    $bar = "'$value'";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ($bar)";
```

Here the result is one of these two:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('baz')
```

Then MySQL will see the `null` as `NULL`.

However, if you're going to such lengths in PHP, you can obviously simply not fire the query if your values are empty, instead of firing the query and letting MySQL fail due to constraints.

You further need to [learn about SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/476).

Comment: OK I've used `$name = $_POST["name"];
if(empty($name)){ 
$name='NULL';
} else {
$name = "'$name'";
}` AND `$sql = "INSERT INTO Person
VALUES($name,'$dob','$tob','$city')";` and It is working Fine!

Comment: I'd recommend you to read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) and [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not `NULL`. What you're inserting in your table is an empty string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES('$name','$dob','$tob','$city')";
```

if `$name` is NULL in PHP, this would just result in a string like: `INSERT INTO Person VALUES('','...','...','...')`

If you want to pass `NULL` to MySQL, you have to send `NULL`, not `"NULL"` and not `""`.

```
$nameForMysql = is_null($name) ? "NULL" : "'$name'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES($nameForMysql,'$dob','$tob','$city')";
```

Comment: `Error: INSERT INTO Person VALUES(NULL,'--','','')`

Comment: That error message is exactly what you were asking for! :-) now you've sent NULL to datatable, and sql generate exception with error, according to the table fields declaration :-)

Comment: OK. The full output I get is: Name is Required
Error: INSERT INTO Person VALUES(NULL,'--','','')
**Column 'Name' cannot be null** and I accepted you answer!

Comment: I found that [deceze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28390955/4493879) already have similar solution before; so I accepted it!

Answer (score 1):

So just make your `if...else` more wide:

```
if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["name"])){ echo "Name is Required<br>";}
else {
$name = $_POST["name"];
$tob = $_POST["tob"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$dd = $_POST["dd"];
$mm = $_POST["mm"];
$yyyy = $_POST["yyyy"];

$dob = "$yyyy-$mm-$dd";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Inserting Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO Person
VALUES('$name','$dob','$tob','$city')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: This is not use of `NOT NULL` actually!

Comment: I agree with you. But to catch `null` in php  and convert/send it as `NULL` to sql table that doesn't accept it is more complicated and has no sense in this particular case. IMHO :-)

Answer (score 1):

Specify NULL where there is no value, sql is treating your data as empty string not null so Use the code below

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<style>
label{text-align:left;
       width:150px;
       display:block;
           float:left;
           clear:right;
       font-size:18;}

form {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<label>Name:</label><input name=name autocomplete=off><br>
<label>Date of Birth:</label><input size=2 name=dd placeholder=dd> / <input size=2 name=mm placeholder=mm> / <input size=6 name=yyyy placeholder=yyyy><br>
<label>Time of Birth:</label><input name=tob placeholder="hh : mm : ss"><br>
<label>City:</label><input name=city><br><br>
<center><input type=submit value=Save></center>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "userame";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB2";
if(empty($_POST["name"])){ echo "Name is Required<br>";
$name = "NULL";
}
else {
$name = $_POST["name"];
}
var_dump($name);
$tob = $_POST["tob"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$dd = $_POST["dd"];
$mm = $_POST["mm"];
$yyyy = $_POST["yyyy"];

$dob = "$yyyy-$mm-$dd";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Inserting Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO Person
VALUES('$name','$dob','$tob','$city')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This enters string `NULL` to `$name` and hence `Name` Column; Here there is **No** use of **`NOT NULL`** actually!